# Make additional search query implement OR rather than AND

Tags: php, laravel, datatables, yajra-datatable

I just tried yajrabox datatables for laravel.
And used HTML builder to generate a datatables.

This is script for the search query.

```
public function query(User $model)
{

    if(request()->input('search')['value'] != null){
        $search = request()->input('search')['value'];
        $allIds = \DB::table('countries')->select('id')->where('name','like','%'.$search.'%')->pluck('id');
        return $model->whereIn('country_id',$allIds,'or');
    }
    return $model->newQuery()->withTrashed();
}
```

With that script, generate a query like this.

```
select * from `users` left join `role_user` on `users`.`id` = `user_id` where `country_id` = ? and (LOWER(`users`.`name`) LIKE ? or LOWER(`users`.`email`) LIKE ?) and `users`.`deleted_at` is null order by `user_id` desc limit 10 offset 0
```

I think yajrabox adds default query at that script, but the problem is, it using 'AND' rather than 'OR', so when I'm searching 'af' at the magic search box. That will show several rows with 'af' AND (user with name 'af' OR email 'af').

What I want to achieve is I want to make query that show 'af' country OR user with name 'af' OR email 'af'